# Action Link in Knockout foreach data binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind data to Action Link within Knockoutjs `foreach` loop. This code works fine

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ItemList">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Items", "ItemController")' }" >
              LinkText
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I also need to bind a parameter and bind the LinkText with knockoutjs. I tried different code samples but nothing seems to work.

Final code should be something like,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ItemList">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Items", "ItemController")', new { id = DataBindId)' }" >
              DataBindName
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: DataBindID and DataBindName come from JavaScript right?

Comment: @TomiLammi Yes DataBindID and DataBindName is in KO model (Item in ItemList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Items", "ItemController")?id=' + DataBindId }, text: DataBindName" >
 </a>
```

Which should output something like...

```
<a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '/Item/Items?id=' + DataBindId }, text: DataBindName" >
 </a>
```

Comment: I tried this, but Controller and Action are filled with null. It ends up beeing <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '?id=' + objectId}